# can I call a teller in a bank a cashier?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the dictionaries

> [teller](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/teller?q=teller) noun  /ˈtelə(r)/  /ˈtelər/ ​(especially North American English)
> a person who works **in a bank**, receiving and paying out money from and
> to customers

> [cashier](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cashier_1?q=cashier) noun  /kæˈʃɪə(r)/  /kæˈʃɪr/ ​a person whose job is to receive
> and pay out money in **a bank**, shop, hotel, etc.

When you are at a bank, you want to a person who can help you to open an account/ put some money into or take some money out of the account.

Can that person be called "**a cashier**"?

I suspect a cashier in a bank might just take and pay the money from or to customers.

A teller might do some tasks of a cashier but can do some more such consulting, opening or closing an account, setting up internet banking etc.

Comment: First hit research from Wikipedia answers this question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_teller#:~:text=A%20bank%20teller%20(often%20abbreviated,customer%20service%20at%20a%20branch. You need to post or show research. Don't confuse a banker at a bank with a bank teller (AKA cashier).

Comment: @Lambie, you tried to make up things I have never said. I did not mention "banker" in my question. Of course, I know what a banker is. I am not fool enough not to distinguish between "banker" and "teller".

Comment: You wrote: "When you are at a bank, you want to a person who can help you to open an account". That would not be a teller who does that. That would be a banker. You also say cashier and teller do different things, they don't. It is the same job and **all they do** is make deposits of cash/checks into accounts and pay out cash withdrawals. They don't open/close accounts or setting up Internet banking, which you can do yourself with an app .

Comment: @Lambie, you are wrong: banker noun: ​a person who owns a bank or has an important job at a bank (Oxford). A banker is not going to spend time opening a bank account for you.

Comment: (retail) banker: Retail bankers are often known as customer service representatives or personal bankers, reflecting the customer-focused elements of the role. They work for high street banks, where they offer customers financial guidance, advise them of suitable products and services, and assist them with banking needs. That is for the UK: https://targetjobs.co.uk/careers-advice/job-descriptions/retail-banker-job-description So, James is right.

Comment: I went to my bank Friday (in the US), and spoke with a banker about making changes to my accounts. He was not a teller/cashier. See this: https://careers.jpmorgan.com/us/en/chase/chase-associate-banker Typically, a banker does open an accout for you. You sit at a desk and fill out the papers. Tellers/cashiers do not do that.

Comment: @Lambie, so different banks have different procedures. I went to a bank.met a teller and asked her to open an account for me. She then went to someone in higher position and had the paper signed and she came back to me and gave me my new account. A banker is a big word, she might give some financial advice. But a teller I met just did some basic tasks.

Comment: @Tom It may be different in Vietnam. Banker is not **really** a big word in the West. Generally, **in the West**, tellers/cashiers sit at teller windows and handle deposits/withdrawals.

Comment: "She then went to someone in higher position". Right, she had to get a banker to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Cashier (mostly British) and teller (Mostly US) are different dialect terms for the same thing.

But, this is all rather out of date for how a modern bank looks.

There are a line of automatic teller machines for taking money out and paying  money in.  There will likely be some people with job titles like "Customer Service Associate".  One is likely to be greeting customers, finding out what service they need and directing them to either the ATMs or another person, who might be a "Mortgage service advisor".  There may be another "Customer service associate" who is working as a cashier or teller (usually "cashier" in British English perhaps "teller" in US English).  There are likely a number of offices, perhaps glass-walled offices where you can meet with a mortgage advisor or an investment advisor - they will also be customer service officers, but they have received additional training.

So "cashier" is not a job.  It is just one role that a customer-facing bank worker may take from time to time during the day.

Of course people don't say "I'm a customer service associate".  They would just say "I work in a bank."

Comment: Despite all that, a banker is not a teller (cashier). And is it most definitely not out of date. Just yesterday in fact, I called my bank to make some major changes to my accounts, and the young man said for me to come into the branch and speak to a banker about that.

Comment: Yes, but dealing with "paying in and taking out" is not a major part of a "customer service officer" of a bank, because 1) use of cash is pretty uncommon now and 2) such services are provided by the ATMs.  So the people who work in branches are all dealing with financial advice, investments, loans etc. (but could then do the "cashier" role, if needed)

Comment: James, I am not going to play twinkletoes here. The OP asked about the term banker and cashier and teller. You don't make the case for the term banker at all. It's fine to point out the apparent obsolescense of cashier/teller, but admit you missed the boat on banker.

Comment: OP never mentioned 'banker', only teller & cashier, in a bank.

Comment: @Lambie, you tried to make up things  I have never said. I did not mention "banker" in my question. Of course, I know what a banker is. I am not fool enough not to distinguish between "banker" and "teller".

Comment: @Tom Often, an OP will ask a question that involves not having stated something. People who work in banks are: Bankers, cashiers/tellers and security guards. It does not matter whether you mentioned it in your question. A banker is not always a "grand" personage.